# Advanced Search not affected by Date Preferences

Tags: date-range

Using 5.24.4 I have changed the date ranges at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?action=reset=1 to 20 or 30 but Advanced Search is still showing Activities, Memberships and Events, etc. as 10 years prior and 10 years future.  I have clearned cache civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1 to no effect.

Any ideas where these settings are changed now?

Comment: There was a ticket to replace all the calendar widgets and maybe something got missed? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/561